# Conditional calculations in R

Tags: r, lookup

I have a dataframe with categories and values. Based on the category I want to subtract values that are stored in another table.

```
myframe <- data.frame(
         x = factor(c("A", "D", "A", "C")), 
         y = c(8, 3, 9, 9))

reference <- c('A'= 1, 'B'= 2, 'C'= 3, 'D'= 4)
```

The desired (y-ref) outcome would be:

```
result <- data.frame(
         x = factor(c("A", "D", "A", "C")), 
         y = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
         r = c(7, -1, 8, 6))

      x y  r
    1 A 8  7        
    2 D 3 -1
    3 A 9  8
    4 C 9  6
```

The reference 'table' is a named vector in this case but it could be changed to a better suited data format.

I am not sure how to accomplish this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly straight forward task using `match` and `[`...

```
myframe$r <- myframe$y - reference[ match( myframe$x , names( reference ) ) ]
#  x y  r
#1 A 8  7
#2 D 3 -1
#3 A 9  8
#4 C 9  6
```

Pretty sure this is a (several-times over) duplicate so we should find you a good pointer and close the question (but I commend you for showing input data and desired result, many questions are often not that well laid out).

#### EDIT

Well there are many, *many* `match` based questions on the site. It's hard to pick one to point to as an exact duplicate. But I suggest having a browse of a few of these by searching for "[r](/questions/tagged/r) match" (you can search by specific tags by enclosing the search term in square brackets like this `"[r]"`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Usually, I avoid asking questions without doing research first but this time I did not exactly know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table and set key for the upcoming merge
dt = data.table(myframe, key = 'x')
ref = data.table(x = names(reference), val = reference)

# merge and add a new column
dt[ref, r := y - val]
dt
#   x y  r
#1: A 8  7
#2: A 9  8
#3: C 9  6
#4: D 3 -1
```